# Restore Etcd Quorum

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, etcd, kops

I have a Kubernetes cluster distributed on AWS via Kops consisting of 3 master nodes, each in a different AZ. As is well known, Kops realizes the deployment of a cluster where **Etcd is executed on each master node** through two pods, each of which mounts an EBS volume for saving the state. If you **lose the volumes** of **2 of the 3** masters, you automatically **lose consensus** among the masters.

Is there a way to use information about the only master who still has the status of the cluster, and **retrieve the Quorum between the three masters** on that state? I recreated this scenario, but the cluster becomes unavailable, and I can no longer access the Etcd pods of any of the 3 masters, because those pods fail with an error. Moreover, Etcd itself becomes read-only and it is impossible to add or remove members of the cluster, to try to perform manual interventions.

Tips? Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 1):

This is documented [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/assembly_restore-etcd-quorum.html). There's also another guide [here](https://blog.containership.io/etcd)

You basically have to backup your cluster and create a brand new one.